# Using "New Terminal at Folder" with tmux?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I like to use tmux with Terminal so that I can easily split panes, switch off of long-running tasks, or just close the Terminal window and re-open it to find myself exactly where I left off.

Although there's one feature of OS X that I noticed stopped working when I started using tmux:

[image]

When I click this button it opens up a new Terminal window, but it attaches to my tmux session and I'm in whatever folder I was in last time, not the one I just tried to open.

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

In case it's part of the problem or cause, here's my tmux config:

```
# Use 256 color (if supported)
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"


# Increased scrollback history
set-option -g history-limit 100000


# Vim key bindings
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind [ copy-mode
bind -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection
bind -T copy-mode-vi R send-keys -X rectangle-toggle
bind ] paste-buffer
bind Space choose-buffer


# It makes no sense that the "first" pane is on the far right
set -g base-index 1


# Split panes using | and - (visually representative of splits)
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v


# Switch panes using Alt-arrow without prefix
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D


# Also switch using Alt-vim keys
bind -n M-h select-pane -L
bind -n M-l select-pane -R
bind -n M-k select-pane -U
bind -n M-j select-pane -D


# Also Ctrl+B followed by vim keys
bind h select-pane -L
bind l select-pane -R
bind k select-pane -U
bind j select-pane -D


# Enable mouse control
set -g mouse on


# Don't rename windows automatically
set-option -g allow-rename off


# Leave sessions alive until manually killed
set-option -g destroy-unattached off


# Reload config easily (since zsh means we're always in tmux)
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf


# No delay for escape key press
set -sg escape-time 0


# Update status bar more frequently (for CPU / mem stats)
set -g status-interval 2


# Show computer info on the status bar
set -g status-left-length 120
set -g status-right-length 120
set -g status-bg colour7
set -g status-left "#(~/.tmux.d/left.sh #{client_width})"
set -g status-right "#(~/.tmux.d/right.sh #{client_width})"


# Enable copy/paste from tmux to GUI
bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe "pbcopy"
```